The precision displayed when querying float type fields in MySQL is not complete
I created a table and inserted a row of data using the statement below
CREATE TABLE float_example(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    float_col FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO float_example (id,float_col) VALUES (1,123.456789);

When using the query statement below for verification, it can be seen that the actual precision has reached at least four decimal places, but only two are displayed
SELECT ROUND(float_col,6),float_col from float_example where id=1;

How should I set it up to display the maximum precision that IEEE floating-point numbers can represent in MySQL?

Not with you https://dbfiddle.uk/bL35p-92 looks fine, What do you expect? What platform are you on? What version of mysql are you on?

MySQL version: 8.0.26,use JDBC to connect to MySQL

Platform - windows,linix,unix macos..?

MySQL is set up using Docker in Linux and connected via JDBC in Windows

Is there a reason you are using approximate numbers (float/double) rather than decimal?

I am synchronizing and migrating MySQL data, and the table contains float types

Since you do not provide any precision, your FLOAT value is not restricted
According to documentation:

For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric data values should use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION with no specification of precision or number of digits.

So it means that you can store virtually any precision.

What you see with float_col being 123.457 is just MySql presentation of float. To get values in needed precision, use rounding (as in your first select operation)
Check this DB Fiddle

As you can see, there is even more values in floating point, than you inserted. That's why you can't accurratly compare float values.
To properly compare floats, use methods listed here

I understand that floating-point numbers are stored using the IEEE standard, and I need to obtain the actual value represented by the IEEE single-precision floating-point number stored in MySQL, which cannot be achieved using round()
